# How does TCP session works in a DSR Load Balancer (L4) solution?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, tcp

Let's imagine a client `A` watching a live stream (which translates to a bunch of HTTP requests) with `keep-alive` header on.

```
    A -r-> LB-----> R1 --|
   /|\      |-----> R2 --|
    |       ------> R3 --| 
    |---R----------------|
```

Is it possible that this DSR (direct server return) Load Balancer (L4) offers `least-conn` method?

If it's yes, how does the `reals` manage to work with TCP sequence number? (and also to `keepalive` the connection) Since for each new client connection, the LB can route you to a different `real server`.

[image: load balancing dsr]
<sub>(source: [haproxy.com](http://blog.haproxy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/layer4_dsr_data_flow.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using DSR then the load-balancer is not proxying the TCP connection, and so must not alter sequence or acknowledgement numbers.  It's not fashionable these days as it's limited in functionality, and needs to be coupled to the farm at layer 2 which does not lend itself to hosting multiple services or load-balancing across multiple data centres, plus modern load-balancers run on much more powerful hardware.

Comment: Thanks, the DSR should be layer 3 or lower, isn't? If yes, then it acts more like a router. Even in this case, it should "persist" connection IP to a given `real server` otherwise, each new server would need to reset the TCP, establish a new TCP...

Comment: If you're using least-conns then it must keep track of sessions, but if you were to use source IP distribution then it wouldn't even need to do that, it could be entirely stateless!